permanent rerendering content when moving vue component arround
I have a problem with a window component.
<div class="text-container" ref="infoRef" :style="transformStyle">  
  <div class="handle toucher deselect"></div>
  <p class="headline deselect" v-html="getHeadline()"></p>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="copy-container">

    <div v-if="showclose==true">
      <div class="copy scrollable-area deselect" v-html="store.state.content.impressum.copy"></div>
    </div>
            
    <div v-if="showclose==false">
                
      <div v-for="(item, key, index) in store.state.content.steps[contentStep]" :key="index">
         <div v-if="getbaseKey(key)=='copy'">
            <div class="copy scrollable-area deselect" v-html="item"></div>
         </div>

         <div v-if="getbaseKey(key)=='final'">
           <div class="copy scrollable-area deselect" v-html="item"></div>
         </div>

         <div v-if="getbaseKey(key)=='bild'">
           <img :src="item.image" alt="">
           <p class="bu" v-html="item.bu"></p>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>

On the div "text-container" there is a transformStyle() method that does the transformation.
 const transformStyle = computed(() => {
   // console.log("transformStyle", cardTransformer.x);

   if(closed.value == false) {
     return { 
       transform: `translate3d(${cardTransformer.x}px,${cardTransformer.y}px, 0px) rotate(${cardTransformer.rotate}deg) scale(${cardTransformer.scale})`,
       // backgroundColor: '#f00',
       width: uCurrWidth.value + "px", 
       height: uCurrHeight.value + "px", 
     }
   } else {
     return { 
       transform: `translate3d(${cardTransformer.x}px,${cardTransformer.y}px, 0px) rotate(${cardTransformer.rotate}deg) scale(${cardTransformer.scale})`,
       // backgroundColor: '#f00',
       width: uCurrWidth.value + "px", 
       height: "50px", 
     }
   }
            
 })

I have now discovered that the content of the v-for loop is constantly being executed during the movement. Neither the content nor the contentStep change, but the content is constantly being re-rendered.

Use some kind of item.id to make it unique rather than index for the key. Might be a good start. Then check your Vue devtools for any suspicious state.

I have already tried this without success. It only occurs when transforming the position.

Does it change some indexes or alike?

I'm confused that the getbaseKey call is called four times with the same key. To understand, in a json file there are entries for different media types. image_#, copy_# zoom_# to display different content. v-for goes through these entries, but calls each one 4 times before the next getbaseKey is output in the console.

Put a conditional on that to only run it once then.
